# Macro Shortcut Error when set to a CTRL SHIFT LETTER instead of CTRL LETTER

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to apply formatting from a template sheet to an active sheet. When i run the macro as CTRL + SHIFT + "Letter" the macro starts running, opens my template file and stops, whereas when the macro is set to CTRL + "LETTER" the macro runs fine.

Does someone know why this is an issue and how to get the SHIFT this working smooth?
I have the code below for reference without the full file path for the template

```
Sub Format_IE_STATUS()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim dwb As Workbook
Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = ActiveSheet


Set Mwb = Workbooks.Open("S:\I&E Status Report Template.xlsx")

Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
   WS.Activate


Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With

ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
    
    
Mwb.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Complete"


End Sub
```

Comment: https://jkp-ads.com/articles/workbookopenbug.asp. It's a bug.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your help ! and thanks for the corrections to the code before, ill update it for all

Comment: With that code you edited, it ran perfectly fine for me. this is going to work based on the shortcut i set within excel correct? (changing to the other letters previously mentioned) i didnt see anything that stands out as needing to change for that within the code, albeit im pretty green to the language. additionally is there something i can add other than a select cell that allows the end product to display without the sheet being highlighted?

Comment: If I understand your first question, yes. Regarding your second, you could add a `ws.Range("A2").Select` or similar near the end.

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear, When you pull up the macro options in excel and assign the shortcut to CTRL SHIFT LETTER, i dont need to change anything within the code(Changing the letter from I to H for example), it will just work with whatever letter i assign for the different templates.

Comment: As far as I know, should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://jkp-ads.com/articles/workbookopenbug.asp).

Side note: best to avoid using `Select` and fully qualify your `Range` and `Cells` calls.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "USER32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "USER32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If

Const SHIFT_KEY As Long = &H10

Function ShiftPressed() As Boolean
    'Returns True if shift key is pressed
    ShiftPressed = GetKeyState(SHIFT_KEY) < 0
End Function

Sub Format_IE_STATUS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While ShiftPressed()
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Dim mwb As Workbook
    Set mwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\A7411\Desktop\SO\I&E Status Report Template.xlsx")

    mwb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ws.Parent.Activate
    ws.Activate

    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

    mwb.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: I imported this and set it back to the CTRL SHIFT shortcut and came to the same issue. it pulls the template file then stops, no errors pop up

Comment: no, i noticed earlier it was causing that to be read only and first thought that was the issue

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + I

Comment: but once figured out i plan to use other letters since were setting this up for a few templates, so it will be R, H, W U as well